# Which part is modified?

Tags: sentence-structure, parsing

I'd like to know which part of the sentence is modified by the "to infinitive" enclosed in parentheses?

> Facebook's free Wi-Fi plan includes not only drones, but also low earth orbit satellites and even laser beams (to boost Internet connections in remote areas).

Answer (score -1):

Only by context, including my knowledge of science and engineering, can I say that "(to boost Internet connections in remote areas)" must refer to "laser beams". It couldn't possibly apply to low earth orbit satellites.

However, linguistically, it's ambiguous. It could apply to both satellites and laser beams, but not drones, because the former are part of one prepositional phrase, "but also ...". It could apply to drones, satellites, and laser beams, because it linguistically it could apply to the entire sentence.

The real problem is that the entire sentence is poorly written. "not only ... but also ... and even ..." is the way a child writes.

A proper way to write the sentence is (assuming the parenthetical applies only to laser beams) would be:

"Facebook's free Wi-Fi plan includes drones, low orbit satellites, and, to boost Internet connections in remote areas, laser beams." I think it's reasonable to omit "earth" from "low earth orbit".

Comment: Eh? LEO satellites would absolutely be used to "boost Internet connections" in remote areas, as would drones. In fact, "laser beams" would be perhaps the worst way to "boost Internet connections" in remote areas. 1. LASERs are LoS, only. 2. The attenuation through the atmosphere of the high frequencies that LASERs use is very high.

Answer (score -1):

The best rewrite of the sentence (to aid understanding) is:

> Facebook ... includes ... (things) ... (in order) to boost Internet connections...

Therefore, **"to boost" modifies "includes"**. Why does Facebook include (things)? "To boost..."